# What is the purpose of the extra table in a many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I am trying to understand the need for the "extra" table in a many to many relationship.

For example if my ERD has: `Product m----- <makes> ----n Factory`, the following code for the tables might look like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE factory(

        factory_id      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        address         VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_factory_factory_id PRIMARY KEY(factory_id)
);


 CREATE TABLE product(

        prod_id         INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        prod_name       VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
        price           FLOAT           NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_product_prod_id PRIMARY KEY(prod_id)
);


CREATE TABLE makes(

        prod_id         INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        factory_id      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_makes_prod_id_factory_id PRIMARY KEY(prod_id, factory_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_product_prod_id FOREIGN KEY(prod_id) REFERENCES product(prod_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_factory_factory_id FOREIGN KEY(factory_id) REFERENCES factory(factory_id)
);
```

What is the purpose of the makes table? I can't think of a time when you might use it or why it is necessary.

Comment: `invoice` -- `invoiceLine` isn't normally a many-to-many relationship.  In fact it's usually used as a classic Master-Detail (one-to-many) relation.  That may be making this harder to understand.  Instead, think of the relationship between `Clubs` and `Members`.

Answer (score 1):

How would you record the fact that a single product can be made by each of N factories without it?

- You can't store a single factory number in the product table; there are lots of possible values.
- You can't store a single product number in the factory table; there are lots of possible values.

So, you need the third table to store the information accurately.

> Could you provide an example of how you would then create a query to view the multiple factories that could make a single product?

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM Factory AS f
  JOIN Makes   AS m ON m.factory_id = f.factory_id
 WHERE f.prod_id = 123456;
```

Or:

```
SELECT f.*
  FROM Factory AS f
  JOIN Makes   AS m ON m.factory_id = f.factory_id
  JOIN Product AS p ON m.prod_id    = p.prod_id
 WHERE p.prod_name = "HyperCubic Widget"
```

Which you use depends on whether you know the product ID or whether you need to look the product name or other attributes.

The queries are almost symmetric for if you need to know which products a factory can make:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM Product AS p
  JOIN Makes   AS m ON m.prod_id = f.prod_id
 WHERE f.factory_id = 321;
```

Or:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM Product AS p
  JOIN Makes   AS m ON m.prod_id    = p.prod_id
  JOIN Product AS p ON m.factory_id = f.factory_id
 WHERE f.address = "123 North St, Bigtown"
```

Note that because you will have referential integrity constraints on the tables, you can use inner joins rather than outer joins, which are generally more efficient.

Comment: perhaps to clarify, could you provide an example of how you would then create a query to view the multiple factories that could make a single product

Answer (score 1):

A has-and-belongs-to-many relationship implies that both sides can belong to multiples of one another.

In this case:

- Multiple factories can make a single product
- One factory can make multiple products

The only way to represent this is to have a "join" table, since each item in the factory table and product table only represent one distinct product or factory, there's no way to link it to multiple other items without such a table.

Comment: perhaps to clarify, could you provide an example of how you would then create a query to view the multiple factories that could make a single product?

Comment: Sure @ZAX - you can use something like the following, where you would replace the `123` with the ID of the product you wanted to find the factories for:
`SELECT factory.name FROM factory_product LEFT JOIN factory ON factory.id = factory_product.factory_id WHERE factory_product.id = 123`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some questions that you would answer with it:

```
What products does a single factory make?

What factories make a particular product?

What factories make the same product as factory F?

What factories can be used to fulfill an order that that has products P1, P2, and P3?

Where is the closest factory to the customer who wants production P?

Where is the next closest factory?
```

And so on.